QTableView not showing QPixmap
I'm trying to show a list of media files with Qt. For that I'm using a QTableView with a column for the preview and a column for the file name. With the following code, the file name is shown but the preview column stays empty.
#include <filesystem>

#include <QHeaderView>
#include <QImage>
#include <QImageReader>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QVariant>

#include <easyqt/logging.hxx>

#include "medialist.hxx"

namespace pelican {
    MediaList::MediaList() {
        verticalHeader()->hide();
        
        _model = new QStandardItemModel;
        setModel(_model);
        _model->setHorizontalHeaderLabels({"Preview", "Filename"});
        
        std::filesystem::path mediaPath("/home/username/Pictures/Q");
        
        long long int row = 0;
        for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(mediaPath)) {
            QImage preview(entry.path().c_str());
            QStandardItem* previewItem = new QStandardItem();
            previewItem->setData(QVariant(QPixmap::fromImage(preview)), Qt::DecorationRole);
            _model->setItem(row, 0, previewItem);
            _model->setData(_model->index(row, 1), entry.path().c_str());
        }
    }
}


I was able to get it to work by replacing QVariant with a QIcon in previewItem->setData. The working code:
    MediaList::MediaList() {
        verticalHeader()->hide();
        
        _model = new QStandardItemModel;
        setModel(_model);
        _model->setHorizontalHeaderLabels({"Preview", "Filename"});
        
        std::filesystem::path mediaPath("/home/username/Pictures");
        
        long long int row = 0;
        for (const auto& entry : std::filesystem::directory_iterator(mediaPath)) {
            QImage preview(entry.path().c_str());
            QStandardItem* previewItem = new QStandardItem();
            previewItem->setData(QIcon(QPixmap::fromImage(preview)), Qt::DecorationRole);
            _model->setItem(row, 0, previewItem);
            _model->setData(_model->index(row, 1), entry.path().c_str());
        }
    }

